# HTML 5 Complex Search UI

Tags: search, angularjs, user-interface

Does any one know of an open source control that will do something similar to the image below?

This is from a Silverlight app that I previously worked on but I am now doing a new app using AngularJS / HTML and would like to have similar functionality.

The control allows the user to build a search query, the server code is all in place, I don't need that, I just need something to allow me to do something similar to below:
[image: Complex Searching UI]

The "And"'s can be changed to "OR"'s, the 'x' is used to delete a row / sub-query; and the '+' next to the "AND" is used to add a row to the overall query or to the sub-query.  The '+' next at the end of a row starts a sub-query

Comment: Have you done anything to start with? Any design?

Comment: Anything to start with?  Design = yes the image above

Comment: You misunderstood the meaning of design. The image above is the design of the user interface. The design I am talking about is the design of the the front end model/code to allow this.